# How to use "come true" for something other than hopes and dreams and wishes?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

I'm from Italy and my mother-tongue is not English, so sorry in advance for my mistakes. This is my question:

I know how to use *come true* in sentences like:

> I wish my dreams would come true.

But can I use *come true* in other contexts, like for example

> This feeling **comes true**.

In which it *come true* carries the meaning of something becoming real?

Or it can be applied only with words like *wishes*, *dreams*, and the like?

Comment: Your question may be more suited to our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can't use it with "feeling", but what would it mean if you could? What does it mean for a feeling to become real? You can use it with some other non-real things, like "story".

Comment: "This feeling comes true" would probably be understood, but it is not idiomatic ('normal') British English.  I can't comment more than that.

Comment: To come true : to be realized. For instance, dreams, nightmares or fears can come true.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'm sorry, I didn't know the site you suggested me. I'm sorry if my question was kind of inappropriate, you've been very kind. Best regards

Comment: If you don't like "come true" you could always use "realized".

Comment: People commonly refer to a prediction coming true.  A feeling is somewhat ambiguous, it can refer to something that can come true, like a premonition, or something more of a sensation or emotion.  "Come true" seems to be used only with terms that unambiguously can become a reality.

Comment: I'm commenting since I'm not sure if my interpretation is right. When you write "something becomes real" I assume the something isn't the feeling. You have a feeling about something and what you felt or thought turns out to be true.
If I've correctly understood then  [vindicated](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vindicate) might work, in the sense that you were justified in having such a feeling.
*Subsequent events vindicated his policy*

Comment: A wish is a notion/visualisation of a possible (bright, one assumes) future / future event. How do 'feelings' etc convey this? If someone is happy, they talk about 'wishing this could go on forever'.

Comment: Talking of Italians, “Fairy tales can come true, it can happen to you …” Frank Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

The only senses in which I can imagine the phrase "come true" being used when discussing anything other than predictions or dreams is in relation to

A: [Breeding plants and animals](https://biologydictionary.net/true-breeding/) and

B: In the discussion of materials which distort under some conditions but return to a straight shape when the conditions change.

For example I can imagine

A: That breeders might say, after a long period working on a new breed of animal or variety of plant that it had "come true" in the sense that examples of the animal demonstrate the desired characteristics reliably when both parents are of the new breed or that plant does the same when the parent plant is self-fertilised or fertilised by another example of the variety.

B: That a woodworker might say that a piece of wood (perhaps a door) which had warped when it got wet "came true" when it dried out.

Even if these expressions are used (and I have no evidence that they are) they would be technical ones and not of the same nature as "a dream come true".

Answer (score 0):

*Dreams come true* is idiomatic in English, and most of the variants you see on this — dreams, wishes, etc. — are plays on this idiom.

Consider nightmares, for instance: while a nightmare could “come true”, we tend to say instead that they’re “made real”, which is a different idiom.

Answer (score -2):

Come true - happen,occur,take place, be realized,be fulfilled and become a reality / avverarsi(Italian)

You can use it with feelings i.e, "One day I wish my feelings would come true"

Refer http://www.dictionary.com/browse/come--true

Comment: In your example: "came true" or "would come true", not "come true". Or eventually "I wish for my feelings to come true." However I don't think a feeling can come true, but you rather have it or don't.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I say: "I can trust this feeling that comes true", is it right? Does it make sense? Thank you again!

Comment: @Luca "I can trust this feeling to come true" meaning that you are certain that this feeling will come true.

Comment: @Luca I wish this feeling would/to come true

Comment: @Sudharsan Your citation does not support your answer.  Your dictionary quotes "true feelings" - that is not the same as saying your "feelings come true".

Comment: @MorganFR You first comment above states that "you ... have [feelings] or don't".  "have" being the present. You also say "I don't think a feeling can come true".  I agree with those views.  But then your next comment seems to contradict that by mentioning "feeling[s] com[ing] true".  Please clarify.

Comment: @TrevorD I stand by what I first said, the next comment is just a correction to the grammar used by the OP's follow up question. Sorry for the confusion.